# Line of code that I have never seen before

Tags: c++

This is in a piece of C++ code I am looking through at the moment but I have never seen it before. Can someone tell me what it means? Is it just setting the bool to true if the searchText is found?

```
size_t startPos = searchString.find("searchText");
bool found = startPos != std::string::npos;
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation of `std::string::find` and `std::string::npos`?

Comment: surprise, surprise... you are going to see a lot of code you've never seen before

Comment: It wasnt that i had an issue with. Ive not seen the second line written like that before. Just wanted to make sure it was what i thought it was

Comment: the magic of self-documenting code: Instead of "why is the code checking against npos" you ask "is he checking whether it was found". That's, and I am serious, an improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::string::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) returns the position of the searched substring in the given string or [`std::string::npos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) (a constant) if the substring is not found.

Perhaps you would read the code better if it had been written that way:

```
size_t startPos = searchString.find("searchText");

// In the next line, '(' and ')' are not mandatory, but make this easier to read.
bool found = (startPos != std::string::npos);
```

That is, if `startPos` is different from `std::string::npos` then the substring was found.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [std::string::npos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) is simply the 'biggest possible' value. If `startpos` is not that, the search string must've been found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what it does. `std::string::npos` is  a static member constant value with the greatest possible value for an element of type size_t. If `string::find` doesn't find the given text pattern, it returns that value.

Answer (score 0):

Yep that's it. [`string::npos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) is returned by [`string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) if the substring cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/

> This constant is actually defined with a value of -1 (for any trait), which because size_t is an unsigned integral type, becomes the largest possible representable value for this type.

This actually searches a sub string in searchString and sets found to false if none is found or true if the substring exists.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works in two steps:

1. The first line checks if the string `searchText` is found within the variable `searchString` (which I assume to be of std::string type). If the string is found, the method `find()` will return the position where the string was found, if not it will return `std::string::npos`. The result of the `find()` method is stored in `startPos`.
2. The boolean variable `found`  is initialized based on wheather the string was found in step #1 or not. It would have been more readable had it been written as:

   `bool found = (startPos != std::string::npos);`.

Note that `std::string::npos` is a named constant that defined to `-1`, which is the maximum possible value for `size_t` (all `0xFF`s).

Answer (score -1):

It's a function in the `windows.h` library.

Comment: I won't downvote but `std::string` and its associates have **nothing** to do with `windows.h`.